# calendar day view logic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, calendar

I don't know if my logic is right, but I'm trying to implement the calendar day view from scratch. And for implementing the sharing of same space with the same time, its kinda tricky for me.

I have a list of time:

A. 1am - 2am

B. 1am - 2.30am

C. 1.30am - 3am

So basically A-C have a common time of 2am, so they need to share in the same space. So how can do the logic of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hard to this. You should count overlapped tasks, assign to columns ad draw it. In your example we have 3 overlapped task. It means you have to create 3 columns for boxes representing each task.

A. 1am - 2am
B. 1am - 2.30am
C. 4.30am - 3am

This example creates 2 columns because we have only 2 overlapped tasks.

Now, when you loop tasks for count overlappings you can assign each task to specified column. When new column is required - create it.

Next loop is only drawing this boxes in assigned columns. As you can see, we have to loops: one for count overlapping and assigning columns and second for drawing.

Comment: so what should I compare in able to check if it the time is overlap or not?

Comment: Date and time will be enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I've got searching tru the net

To check the overlap:

Let CondA Mean DateRange A Completely After DateRange B (True if StartA > EndB)
Let CondB Mean DateRange A Completely Before DateRange B (True if EndA < StartB)

Then Overlap exists if Neither A Nor B is true ( If one range is neither completely after the other, nor completely before the other, then they must overlap)

Now deMorgan's law, I think it is, says that

Not (A Or B) <=> Not A And Not B

Which means (StartA <= EndB) And (EndA >= StartB)

NOTE: This includes conditions where the edges overlap exactly. If you wish to exclude that, change the >= operators to >, and <= to <

---

So, base on the overlap value, I can determine how many column should I add.